# How to identify and remove unused apt keys?

Tags: apt, security, gnupg

On a typical installation several apt GPG keys are added, be it for PPAs or other sources, and later go unused.

It is hard to identify in the GUI (software-properties) which keys are actually used for which repositories.

Is there an easy way to identify which keys are used at all, so that all the other keys can be removed?

In my opinion this has some security implications. If a repository owner loses their private key and updates the repository to use a new key, lots of people still have the old (non trustworthy) key installed, right?

Comment: If the key changes, lots of people's apt will complain until they update the key.

Comment: A [revocation certificate should be created with the key](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html) and when switching keys, the revocation certificate should be uploaded to keyservers and propagated.  I'm pretty sure `apt` added `KEYREVOKED` checks when they implemented `KEYEXPIRED` but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Also, this is part of why it is recommended to not use `ppa`'s, really.  Great functionality, but it's hard to mix trust of Jill Smith Random PPA and Professional Debian/Ubuntu Maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script that automatically identifies (and optionally deletes) unused GPG keys.

```
#!/bin/bash
#------------------------------------
# Script that identifies and optionally removes unused trusted gpg keys.
# These keys are usually added to install software from non-standard repositories (e.g. PPAs)
# TODO:
# - what if source repo is not reachable
# - dunno why but the delete doesn't actually delete keys anymore ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
# - dunno why but slack key gets detected as unused even if slack is on the system ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
#------------------------------------

usage() { 
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-b] [-d] [-h]" 1>&2
    echo "prints to stdout the unused keys in the format <keyid> <userid>" 1>&2
    echo "-b, backups trusted.gpg and trusted.gpg.d/ appending .bak (requires superuser)" 1>&2
    echo "-d, deletes unused keys (requires superuser)" 1>&2
    echo "-h, shows this help" 1>&2
}

backup=0
delete=0

while getopts ":bdh" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        b)
            backup=1    
            ;;
        d)
            delete=1
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# create directory in /tmp with random name
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
#echo "storing tmp files in $tmpdir" 1>&2

# get list of sources
grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list > "${tmpdir}"/sources

# get list of releases files
# first sed expression removes content between square brackets (such as architecture specifications)
# awk is used to get only the source url and the distro we are using
# the 2 subsequent sed expressions are used piece everything together and generate the url to the Release.gpg file we need
# sort and uniq are used to eliminate duplicate entries
sed -e "s/\[.*\] //" "${tmpdir}/sources" | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | sed -E -e "s/\/? /\/dists\//" | sed -e "s/$/\/Release.gpg/" | sort | uniq > "${tmpdir}"/releases

# for each source, compute the keyid and save it in a file
while read -r url; do
    domain=$(echo $url | awk -F/ '{print $3}')
    #echo "processing ${url}"
    wget -q -T 10 -O "${tmpdir}"/"${domain}"_Release.gpg "$url"
    gpg --list-packets "${tmpdir}"/"${domain}"_Release.gpg | grep "keyid" | grep -Eo "[0-9A-F]{16}" >> "${tmpdir}"/sourcekeyidstemp
done <"${tmpdir}"/releases

# remove duplicate entries
sort "${tmpdir}"/sourcekeyidstemp | uniq > "${tmpdir}"/sourcekeyids

# for each trusted gpg key, extract his keyid and userid
gpg --list-packets /etc/apt/trusted.gpg | grep -A 8 "public key packet" | grep -E "keyid:|user ID" | grep -oE "[0-9A-F]{16}|\".*\""  | awk '{(getline tmp); print $0,tmp}' > "${tmpdir}"/trustedkeys

for f in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*.gpg; do
    gpg --list-packets "$f" | grep -A 8 "public key packet" | grep -E "keyid:|user ID" | grep -oE "[0-9A-F]{16}|\".*\""  | awk '{(getline tmp); print $0,tmp}' >> "${tmpdir}"/trustedkeys
done

# for each trusted gpg key, check if in use
touch "${tmpdir}"/unusedkeys
while read -r line; do
    keyid=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "\"" -f 1)
    userid=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "\"" -f 2)
    check=$(grep ${keyid} "${tmpdir}"/sourcekeyids)
    if [ -z "$check" ]; then
        echo "${keyid} ${userid}" >> "${tmpdir}"/unusedkeys
    fi 
done <"${tmpdir}"/trustedkeys

# backup gpg keys 
if [ $backup -eq 1 ]; then
    sudo cp /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.bak
    sudo cp -r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d.bak
fi

# delete unused gpg keys
if [ $delete -eq 1 ]; then
    while read -r line; do
        keyid=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "\"" -f 1)
        sudo apt-key del "$keyid" >/dev/null 
    done <"${tmpdir}"/unusedkeys
    echo "deleted keys:"
fi

# print unused keys
cat "${tmpdir}"/unusedkeys
```

It is quite clunky but it works. There might be bugs, use at your own risk.

The workflow of the script is the following:

- extract the KEYIDs of all the apt source by fetching the Release.gpg file from the online repository
- extract the KEYIDs of all your local trusted keys.
- check whether some KEYIDs are present locally and not present in the ones extracted from the online sources. Those are the unused keys.

Edit: fixed link
Edit: pasted the code here because I am tired of fixing links

Comment: thank you.
found script at https://linuxsheet.com/answers/1145652u/ , which failed, but this copy worked. maybe a github source for versions? must the the `\` escaping of chars

Answer (score 2):

Removing unused keys is pretty simple, but just like when adding keys, you are the one in charge of doing your homework and deciding which keys are no longer in use and can be removed.

Start by listing the apt keys you currently have with `sudo apt-key list`.

Once you identify a key that you no longer need, you can simply remove it with `sudo apt-key del KEYID`.

With the list command you will usually be able to see for what each key is, specially if it is from a ppa, since it will usually have a uid that includes something like "Launchpad PPA for John". So, if you removed that ppa from the sources and are no longer using it, you can safely remove them.

Sometimes you might need a quick google to know where a speciifc key comes from, for example, the mono key has the uid "Xamarin Public Jenkins", which if you google xamarin you can see where that key came from. Also, you can always go back to your bash history and find the a key that you added if you are unsure.

`man apt-key` is there for more info and other commands.

Comment: Okay, so the question is: Can I test somehow if a key belongs to any of the repos i"m using. If so I could write a script to automatically remove unused keys.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any command for that. If you have too many keys and don't want to go over them, there are clever ways to know which ones are being used or not. If you remove one of the keys, and it is still part of your sources, you will get an error when updating, saying that there is no key available. With this in mind you could certainly write a script that removes a key, tries to update, and if it gets an error, it adds the key back, looping through all the keys one by one. I personally feel it's more work than it's worth, but if you thousands of keys it might pay off.